# My graphics card is not working, everything is really huge

Tags: 10.04, graphics

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device [10de:1040] 
(rev a1)
```

thats what i get when I do

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 , I'm getting really annoyed help please..

Comment: what is your graphics card model? Did you install any additional driver?

Answer (score 1):

This issue gets everyone in Lulliput shaking their cage...

Successfully configuring your display to use your graphics card depends on 2 things:

- The Xserver config file at /etc/X11/xorg.conf
- Having the correct Nvidia driver installed

Your graphics card appears to be an Nvidia GT520 (device code 10de:1040).

1. Open Synaptic and completely remove any package with "nvidia" in the name.
2. Go to *System > Administration > Hardware drivers*. Install or reinstall your Nvidia driver and accept the recommended Nvidia proprietary driver.
3. Install the package *nvidia-settings* via Synaptic and after a reboot run the following:

   $ sudo nvidia-settings

Configure your display and then click "Save Current Settings", then reboot again. You should now have a xorg.conf file with the Device section something like the following:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT520"
EndSection
```

If at this point, you are still having no joy, it's time to get heavy handed, so try each of the following and repeat from the top.

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

or

```
& sudo rm -rf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```